# REACTJS : imageloaded is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to create the exact scroll effect like below JSFiddle code into a react project [Jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/Adarsh99/s5htobxa/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div data-scroll>
  <div data-scroll-content>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
      <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
     <figure>
       <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/58281/bg_2.jpg">
     </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}

[data-scroll-content] {
  padding: 10vw 0;
}

figure{
  padding: 10vw 5vw;
  
  img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

**JS**

```
const math = {
    lerp: (a, b, n) => {
        return (1 - n) * a + n * b
    },
    norm: (value, min, max) => {
        return (value - min) / (max - min)
    }
}

const config = {
  height: window.innerHeight,
  width: window.innerWidth
}

class Smooth {
  constructor() {
    this.bindMethods()

    this.data = {
      ease: 0.1,
      current: 0,
      last: 0,
      rounded: 0
    }

    this.dom = {
      el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll]'),
      content: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-content]')
    }

    this.rAF = null

    this.init()
  }

  bindMethods() {
    ['scroll', 'run', 'resize']
    .forEach((fn) => this[fn] = this[fn].bind(this))
  }

  setStyles() {
    Object.assign(this.dom.el.style, {
      position: 'fixed',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      overflow: 'hidden'        
    })   
  }

  setHeight() {
    document.body.style.height = `${this.dom.content.getBoundingClientRect().height}px`
  }

  resize() {
    this.setHeight()
    this.scroll()
  }

  preload() {
    imagesLoaded(this.dom.content, (instance) => {
      this.setHeight()
    })
  }

  scroll() {
    this.data.current = window.scrollY
  }

  run() {
    this.data.last += (this.data.current - this.data.last) * this.data.ease
    this.data.rounded = Math.round(this.data.last * 100) / 100
    
    const diff = this.data.current - this.data.rounded
    const acc = diff / config.width
    const velo =+ acc
    const skew = velo * 7.5
    
    this.dom.content.style.transform = `translate3d(0, -${this.data.rounded}px, 0) skewY(${skew}deg)`

    this.requestAnimationFrame()
  }

  on() { 
    this.setStyles()
    this.setHeight()
    this.addEvents()

    this.requestAnimationFrame()
  }

  off() {
    this.cancelAnimationFrame()

    this.removeEvents()
  }

  requestAnimationFrame() {
    this.rAF = requestAnimationFrame(this.run)
  }

  cancelAnimationFrame() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.rAF)
  }

  destroy() {
    document.body.style.height = ''

    this.data = null

    this.removeEvents()
    this.cancelAnimationFrame()
  }

  resize() {
    this.setHeight()
    this.data.rounded = this.data.last = this.data.current
  }

  addEvents() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize, { passive: true })
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, { passive: true })
  }

  removeEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize, { passive: true })
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.scroll, { passive: true })
  }

  init() {
    this.preload()
    this.on()
  }
}

new Smooth()
```

The above code is working fine, but when i try to use the above js code in react I'm getting an error for

> imagesloaded is not defined

in my codesandbox below [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/smooth-scroll-e00g0?file=/src/App.js) while creating in react project.

Comment: it's not working fine since there is no definition for the imagesLoaded function

Comment: In your sandbox at least you are missing the closing <img> tags

Comment: use npm to install package and if you are codesandbox then u can import it directly . Check out my answer for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install imagesloaded
```

use this command to install imagesloaded in your react project.

and than import it in the js file where you want to use it.

```
import imagesLoaded from "imagesloaded"
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagesloaded

refer this for more.
Move to the Webpack section

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the module with `npm install imagesloaded`, then import it in your component with `import "imagesloaded"`.
More info on how to use `import` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import